# Javascript array into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a struct array like this:

```
SmallArray[0].X , SmallArray[0].Y and 
SmallArray[1].X , SmallArray[1].Y and
```

etc...

Now I have to insert this array to a cell of another array, for example:

```
BigArray[0] = SmallArray   //Not a single cell but the whole small array
```

As if the cell point to the small array so I can access to the small array like this:

```
let variable  = BigArray[0].SmallArray[0].X
let variable2 = BigArray[0].SmallArray[0].Y
```

and also

```
let variable3  = BigArray[0].SmallArray[1].X
let variable4  = BigArray[0].SmallArray[1].Y
```

etc...

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
var variable1 = BigArray[0][0].X
var variable2 = BigArray[0][0].Y
var variable3 = BigArray[0][1].X
var variable4 = BigArray[0][1].Y
```

etc

Comment: It worked, i lost so much time trying to fix by myself but i gave up. Thank you all guys

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to get an array as a child array to an array then:

```
var BigArray = [];
BigArray.push(SmallArray);
```

After this you can reference your values as such:

```
var x0 = BigArray[0][0].X;
var y0 = BigArray[0][0].Y;
```